# How to dismount the middle commit from the git with Sourcetree?

Tags: git, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I have large project. I have a branch whose commits are structured as follows:

```
e 

d

c pod updated successfully with this commit

b

a
```

I want to undo the c commit changes, so I can go on my way with unupdated pods:

```
e

d

b

a
```

So what is the simplest way using Sourcetree ? I am not so much coversant with Git please tell me an easy way.

Comment: Create a branch at `c` and work on that one. Where does the term `pod` come from? It's not git related.

Comment: @fredrik it is a commit name

Comment: @fredrik creating b is fine then I pick the one by one d and e ? I want to omit just c commit, revert works ?

Comment: Commits don't have names, they have a message, a SHA and might have have a tag pointing to them. Perhaps a branch pointing to the last one in the sequence.

Comment: Revert will create a new commit `c'` which is the inverse of c - but it will remove the changes made by c

Comment: but a b d e commits will be there right ? like a b d e c`

Comment: only commits make before c, including c, will be on the new branch.

Comment: edit my question maybe it was not clear

Comment: Well, it looks like you have 5 branches and want to remove 1 so that only 4 remain. `git branch -D c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do an interactive rebase where you delete commit `c`.

I will demonstrate with a simplified sketch with just three commits, a, b, and c, and I will remove the middle one, commit b.

Here we have commits a, b, and c:

[image]

Control-click on commit a, and ask for an interactive rebase:

[image]

In the resulting dialog, select the commit you want to delete, and click Delete. Here, I'll delete commit b.

[image]

Now click OK. The interactive rebase is performed, and you will find that the unwanted commit is gone:

[image]